# elisp pattern for handling region || buffer || file

Tags: buffers, files, region, interactive

### summary

Elisp newbie has been given [interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands) code (aka *commands*, called with `M-x whatever`) that "does stuff" on the currently-selected region in the current buffer. What is an/the "elispish way" to scale that code up to handle all of the following (and all interactive) usecases:

1. *(current)* If called with (no argument `&&` region selected in the current buffer):

   - do something on the text in the region
2. If called with (no argument `&&` no region selected in the current buffer):

   - do something on all the text in the buffer
3. If called with (`C-u filepath M-x whatever`) *(more on this below)*

   - evaluate the argument as a filepath
   - do something on all the text in the file

?

### example

I have code in [this repo](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement) that currently "does stuff" (usecase detailed in [thread beginning here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2015-12/msg00077.html)) on a region in a buffer. The relevant code is part of [this file](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement/src/HEAD/test_code.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (adapted from [original code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/informatimago/emacs/master/pjb-emacs.el) by [Pascal Bourguignon](https://github.com/informatimago/)):

```el
(defun bulk-replace-region-with-tuples-from-file (start end)
  (interactive "r") ; need "r" to get region start and end
  (save-excursion
    (narrow-to-region start end)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (replace-multiple-strings   ; the payload
      (with-file BULK-REPLACE-TUPLES-FILEPATH ; defined earlier in the test code
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (read (current-buffer))
      )
    )
    (widen)
  )
)
```

That works iff ∃region selected in the current buffer, i.e., usecase#=1 above. How to scale to handle the others?

### answer-in-progress

Following [wvxvw](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/563/wvxvw)'s guidance ([below](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19059/5444)), I have

`0.` later discovered that a [prefix argument cannot be a string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html)! Dunno why I thought this: I've been *using* Emacs forever. Instead, if given a non-`nil` prefix argument, I'll hafta prompt for a filepath.

1. Simply refactored `bulk-replace-region-with-tuples-from-file` above into a non-interactive helper `bulk-replace-region-non-interactive`, merely by removing the `(interactive "r")`.
2. Created a `bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive` that simply wraps `bulk-replace-region-non-interactive`:

```el
    (defun bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive ()
      (bulk-replace-region-non-interactive (point-min) (point-max))
    )
```

3. Created a `bulk-replace-file-non-interactive` that simply wraps `bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive`:

```el
    (defun bulk-replace-file-non-interactive (filepath)
      (set-buffer (find-file-noselect filepath))
      (bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive)
      (save-buffer)
      (kill-buffer)
    )
```

4. Created a hardcoded but interactive solution to usecase#=1 by simply wrapping its non-interactive helper. It's mostly for testing the helper, but it's a useful API as well as a "step along the path":

```el
    (defun bulk-replace-region (begin end)
      (interactive "r") ; need "r" to get region begin and end
      (bulk-replace-region-non-interactive begin end) 
    )
```

5. Created a hardcoded but interactive solution to usecase#=2 very similar to previous step:

```el
    (defun bulk-replace-buffer ()
      (interactive) ; purely to enable `M-x`
      (bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive)
    )
```

6. Sorta/kinda handled usecase#=3 in a manner similar to the previous 2 steps: a hardcoded but interactive solution which

   - takes the filepath from a prompt (without a prefix argument). (Note `BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT` is defined above in the [code](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement/src/HEAD/test_code.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).)
   - calls the helper on the filepath
   - [does *not* try to use a parameterized prompt with `(interactive)`!](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19082/how-to-parameterize-prompt-for-interactive-command)

```el
    ; Don't try this! see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19082/5444
    ; (defun bulk-replace-file (filepath)
    ;   (interactive (concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT))

    (defun bulk-replace-file ()
      (interactive) ; purely to enable `M-x`
      (bulk-replace-file-non-interactive
        ; `(read-file-name)` does the prompting
        (expand-file-name (read-file-name BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT))
      ) 
    )
```

7. Handled all the usecases (hopefully--pending more complete testing) with an über-wrapper that hides {API, separate code paths} from the user:

```el
    (defun bulk-replace (prefix-argument)
      (interactive "P")  ; to catch prefix argument (if given)
      (cond
        (prefix-argument ; got one, so prompt user for filepath
          (bulk-replace-file)
        )
        ((use-region-p)  ; we have a region, so bulk-replace-region
          (bulk-replace-region-non-interactive (region-beginning) (region-end))
        )
        (t               ; we always have a current-buffer, so bulk-replace-buffer
          (bulk-replace-buffer-non-interactive)
        )
      )
    )
```

It works! but needs more, better, automated} testing, docstrings, error-handling, etc: [to be continued ...](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the confusing thing is the `interactive` part, so I'll work from it.

## Interactive

Is the part of the function which is executed before the function is called. If it has some particular strings, Emacs will know to interpret those as asking for performing some interaction.  But, more generally, `interactive` form can contain whatever code you like; the requirement is that it produce a list with the arguments matching function's formal arguments.

## Your case

You can have two strategies:

1. `(bulk-replace-current-region-with-tuples-from-file file-or-begin end)`.  In this case you would do something like:

   ```
   (defun bulk-replace-current-region-with-tuples-from-file (file-or-begin &optional end)
     (interactive
       (if (region-active-p)
          (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
          (read-file-name "Replace in file: ")))
     (if end ; this is an operation on region
        ; otherwise perform replacement in a file
     ...)
   ```

   This is an "ugly" function signature because it mixes types, and the meaning of its arguments is ambiguous, but it keeps the number of arguments to the minimum, and every combination of arguments has a meaning.
2. `(bulk-replace-current-region-with-tuples-from-file begin end file)` In this case, your code might look like this:

   ```
    (defun bulk-replace-current-region-with-tuples-from-file (begin end file)
     (interactive
       (if (region-active-p)
          (list (region-beginning) (region-end) nil)
          (list nil nil (read-file-name "Replace in file: ")))
     (cond
        ((and begin end file) ; this is an operation on a region in a file
        )
        (file ; this is an operation on a file
        )
        ( ; this is an operation on a region
        ))
      ...)
   ```

   Unlike in the previous case, you would need to handle the situation when you are both given the file name and the region.  Perhaps, you would also want to be able to specify both of these parameters interactively (in which case you would need to modify the `interactive` part).

---

Since the above seems complicated, my strategy would be to:

1. Write a non-interactive function that does replacement on a region.
2. Write two interactive functions calling the first function in a situation when I need it to work on a buffer, or to switch to the given file and to specify the `begin` and `end` by giving it `(point-min)` and `(point-max)`.  You'd have more functions, but each one of them would be simpler, so it's not so complicated after all.

Comment: I like the design (at end), and would prefer to have more/simpler functions. But shouldn't strategy item#=1 be 'Write a non-interactive function that does replacement on a `region`'? That seems to be the simplest case, no? Then (1) to handle region, pass `begin` and `end` (2) to handle buffer, pass `(point-min)` and `(point-max)` (3) to handle file, switch to it and pass `(point-min)` and `(point-max)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TomRoche yes, I intended to be a region, not a buffer. That was a typo.

Comment: and this is working! see [latest code](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement). Just need an über-wrapper and more thorough testing: provided that doesn't uncover dormant bombs, I'll mark this answer and doc it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your description does not say that the function needs to be a command.  This is essentially what you want, in that case:

```el
(defun foo (&optional file)
  "..."
  (if file
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
        (do-something-with-text-in-file))
    (if (use-region-p)                  ; or (region-active-p)
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
          (do-something-with-text-in-region))
      (do-something-with-text-in-current-buffer))))
```

`use-region-p` assumes you want the active region to be non-empty. If not, use `active-region-p`.  Depending on what you want to do in the region, you might not need to use `save-restriction` -- you can perhaps just bind local variables to `region-beginning` and `region-end`, and work within those bounds.

And no, you do not need to mark the whole buffer to be able to act on it.  Just perform whatever action you want, using `point-min` and `point-max` as the bounds of the action.

If it is the *same* action that you want to do when the region is active, then you can use the same code: if the region is active, just use `save-restriction` and `narrow-to-region` first. Within the narrowed buffer, `point-min` and `point-max` are the beginning and end of the region, not the buffer.

Note that if you do want a *command* then you will need to specify how you want the command to (optionally) get a file-name argument. Do you want to test a prefix argument and depending on its value prompt to read a file name?  And so on.  IOW, you need to decide what *interactive* behavior you want, if you want a command.  For a command, your question is unclear so far.

Comment: good point, I have now edited question to mandate (interactive)-ity.

Comment: It does no good to mandate a command if you do not specify how you expect/want to provide it a file name interactively. IOW, this means **nothing**: "*If called with (argument)*" - *how* is it to be called with an argument, interactively? How do you want to provide a file-name argument interactively - read it? So far, the question is unclear (underspecfied), and should be closed as such.

Comment: Would not `C-u` work? and is not closing rather an overreaction in this case?

Comment: How is your function to be called, so that it receives a file name? If called interactively, you need to say how it is to receive the file-name argument interactively.

Comment: What does "*would not `C-u` work*" mean? Yes, you can define the behavior to interpret a prefix arg in such a way that something, somehow, provides a file-name argument. But you haven't specified that, so far. That's why I suggested that that is one way to provide it: test for a prefix arg and then read it. But I'm not specifying what you want - that's your job. Anyway, you should have enough info now to get what you want. You just need to decide what you want. If you have another question about that (e.g., how to test a prefix arg or read a file name), then post such questions separately.

Comment: Done. That may be my job, and suggesting that is certainly welcome. But recommending that a question be closed because it does not dot every 'i' that you want dotted does *not* seem to be warranted, and ISTM is rather overreacting.

Comment: I did not vote to close your question. I'm trying to help you write a better question, so you get better help - now or later. If you don't try to clarify, yes, there is a risk that it gets closed because it is not clear enough for people to feel like they can help you.

Comment: 'I'm trying to help you write a better question' OK, then thanks. But consider the possibility that I am not alone in perceiving little space between 'the question [...] should be closed' and 'I vote to close the question.' ICBW, YMMV.

Comment: Yep, there is little space between them. And the "*So far,...*" preceding the *should* remains true. *If* the question remains unclear *then* it risks being closed as unclear. That's the point. Do with that info what you will.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

- write a general basic processing defun, with start-end interface
- determine what you has been given
- set start and end
- apply basic processing defun

Here's an implementation. Note though that I didn't test it:

```lisp
(defun extensible-omnivorous-defun (arg)
  "Applyies basic-processing to active region,
or whole buffer if there's no active region.
With C-u brings up a dialog to select the file to process."
  (interactive "P")

  ;; basic processing with start-end interface:
  (defun basic-processing (start end)
    ;; do something here
    )

  ;; determing start and end:
  (let (start end 
              (file-is-given? nil))

    (cond
     ((equal arg '(4))
      (ido-find-file "Select file to process: ")

      (setq start (point-min))
      (setq end   (point-max))

      (setq file-is-given? t)
      )
     ;; ;; easily extend the defun later:
     ;; ((equal arg '(16))
     ;;  (message "%s" arg)
     ;;  )
     ;; ((equal arg '-)
     ;;  (message "%s" arg)
     ;;  )
     (t
      ;; no file name is given
      (if (use-region-p)
          (progn (setq start (region-beginning))
                 (setq end (region-end)) )
        (progn (setq start (point-min))
               (setq end (point-max)) )  )
      )
     )

    ;; applying basic processing to what ever is given:
    (basic-processing start end)
    )

  ;; if it has been file -- save and close it:
  (when file-is-given?
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer)
    )

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the following macro helpful for unifying the first two cases:

```
(defmacro on-region-or-buffer (&rest body)
  `(if (region-active-p)
       (save-restriction
         (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
         ,@body)
     ,@body))
```