# how to parameterize prompt for interactive/command?

Tags: interactive, string, list

### background

I had elisp code (in this [very small `git` repo](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/elisp_bulk_replacement)) like

```el
(defun bulk-replace-file (filepath)
  (interactive "FPath to file to bulk-replace: ")
  (bulk-replace-file-non-interactive filepath)
)
```

That worked. Then I decided to parameterize the prompt, producing code like

```el
(defconst BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT "Path to file to bulk-replace: ")

(defun bulk-replace-file (filepath)
;  (interactive "FPath to file to bulk-replace: ") ; should always work
  (interactive (concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT))
  (bulk-replace-file-non-interactive filepath)
)
```

However that fails with (in `*Messages*`)

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: listp, "FPath to file to bulk-replace: "
```

Which frankly stuns me, esp since I'm positive this code formerly worked, but that's why one does regression testing `:-(`.

### questions

1. How is `(interactive)` getting a list from `"FPath to file to bulk-replace: "`, given that the latter surely *looks* like a string? Am I missing something?
2. Why is `(interactive)` *not* getting a list from `(concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT)`, given that

   - `(concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT)` returns a string (I have checked with `(type-of)`)
   - `(concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT)` == `"FPath to file to bulk-replace: "` (per the error message above)
   - `(interactive "FPath to file to bulk-replace: ")` works (see first code snippet)
3. What's "the right way" to parameterize a prompt used for `(interactive)`?

### über-answer

Given that, as [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) points out, `(interactive)` is [quite demanding](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19083/5444), an easier (and working) way to achieve the desired functionality avoids prompting via `(interactive)`:

```el
(defconst BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT "Path to file to bulk-replace: ")

(defun bulk-replace-file ()
  (interactive) ; Purely to enable `M-x`: let `read-file-name` get the filepath
  (bulk-replace-file-non-interactive
    (read-file-name BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`interactive` is a special form, not a function.  As such, it need not handle its argument as would an ordinary function.

`interactive` expects a **literal** string as argument, or else a sexp that is evaluated to produce the list of arguments for the function.

If the argument is a literal string then the various [interactive codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html) apply. In other words, the string has special formatting, with certain codes (first char and first char after each newline char (`\n`) in the string that are interpreted to produce the list of arguments.

If the argument is a sexp then it must do *everything* to come up with the correct list of arguments.

In your case, you could use a sexp, but it would need to do two things:

1. Construct the prompt -- you know how to do that, using `concat`.
2. Use the prompt to read and return a file name.  For that, you need to use a function such as `read-file-name` (which expects a prompt-string argument).
3. Put the file name in a list.  (`interactive` must return a **list** of all arguments.)

So, for example:

```el
(interactive (list (read-file-name BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT)))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

It is almost always best to **ask Emacs first**.  In this case, in the Elisp manual, use `i interactive RET` to get information about `interactive`, including the answer to this very question.

Comment: `(interactive (list (read-file-name (concat "F" BULK-REPLACE-FILEPATH-PROMPT))))`: did you test that? I know (empirically) that I *don't* want to `concat` the "F" onto the `read-file-name` prompt: `(read-file-name)` displays the prompt normally, while `(interactive)` does not display the "F". So how should one, umm, give `(interactive)` the "F"? (pun intended :-)

Comment: `ask Emacs first`: I would, except that, for reasons unknown (but probably due to my misconfiguration), I *don't* see manual=`Emacs` when I do `C-h i`. Although I *do*, oddly, see manual=`Emacs FAQ`.

Comment: Right. If that was the `F` as the interactive code, then obviously you don't need to prefix the prompt with it. I don't know what your `BULK...PROMPT` string is. If it is the whole prompt string then that's all you need. (Answer updated accordingly.)

Comment: Too bad, if you don't have the Emacs manual. I was talking about the Elisp manual, but maybe you don't have that either, in which case, doubly too bad. Fortunately, these manuals are at least available on the web: [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/), [Elisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/).